# Rasberry Pi not outputting video when using hdmi to vga cable

Tags: video, hdmi, raspberry-pi, vga, adapter

I have a [HP v220 Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWjbP.jpg) and am using a [Vga to Hdmi cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO3w2.jpg) and a Rasberry Pi 2b. I have tried using all the config.txt tutorias out there and I am still failing to output the video to the monitor. Please Help

Comment: That looks like a bogus cable that cannot convert the signals.  You need a HDMI-to-VGA converter, which I've seen can be a cheap as US$3.  See https://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/32722161675.html?uttaskid=35004&utcontentid=976&utalgorithmid=2&tracelog=rowan&rowan_id1=eclc_en_7_1_en_US_2016-11-30&rowan_msg_id=geraUTT_35004_aliexpress.com/item/-/%E2%80%A65c23b25a96b4a7b9061291a5d074449&ck=in_edm_other although I have not used such a cheap one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga

Comment: Consider asking on [Raspberry Pi stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)